# You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache, symfony, virtualhost, linux-mint

I'm on linux mint and I want to configure a virtual host for my symfony 3 application.

this is my Vhost on /etc/apache2/sites-available/evaluation.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName evaluation.dev
ServerAlias www.evaluation.dev
DocumentRoot /home/sahnoun/InternshipPFE/Dev/systeme_evaluation/web
<Directory /home/sahnoun/InternshipPFE/Dev/systeme_evaluation/web>

 AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I've added the host in /etc/hosts like that :

```
127.0.0.1   evaluation.dev
```

That's not wrking for me and it return this error :

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at evaluation.dev Port 8

Comment: Please close VirtualHost directive. See in your httpd.conf if you have virtualhost enabled

Comment: Thanks @Hokusai , yes it's closed i forgot it, I've enabled my vhost, same problem !

Comment: It should be in /conf directory. Also remember put `DirectoryIndex app.php` into `Directory` directive.

Comment: not working also

Comment: If you add Require all granted inside your Directory config since apache 2.4 this new directive replace the override one.

Comment: That's not working also, maybe I should change some thing related to permission for this directory on apache config !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to grand files access rights

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/sahnoun/InternshipPFE/Dev/systeme_evaluation/web
chmod -R 755 /home/sahnoun/InternshipPFE/Dev/systeme_evaluation/web
```

and

move the VirtualHost file from /etc/apache2/sites-available/evaluation.conf to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/evaluation.conf

Comment: replace the Directory tag with this one
`<Directory /home/sahnoun/InternshipPFE/Dev/systeme_evaluation/web>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>`